# Question mark statement with semicolon, do multiple things if true

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-operator

I want a question mark statement and multiple things to do if it's true. Like this:

```
something.includes('read') ? (
    console.log(1);
    console.log(2)
       : console.log(3))
```

Like this I get `')' expected` error at the `;`.
Is this somehow possible? Or do I need to use a if statement here? I want to `console.log` 1 *and* 2 if true.

Comment: Why are you using a conditional/ternary expression for this at all?

Comment: Use an `if` statement. Side-effects in ternary operators are bad style anway.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Control_flow_and_error_handling#conditional_statements

Comment: `? :` is the **conditional operator**, not a "question mark statement" (it's not a statement at all). It's also sometimes called "the ternary operator," but really it's just **a** ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands). It's currently JavaScript's only ternary operator, but that could change.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a use case for the conditional operator (`? :`); just use an `if`:

```
if (something.includes('read')) {
    console.log(1);
    console.log(2);
} else {
    console.log(3);
}
```

For completeness I'll point out that it's *possible* to do the above using the conditional operator combined with the comma operator (`condition ? (firstThing(), secondThing()) : otherThing()`), but please don't. There's no good reason to, and it impairs readability.